# Can we limit operations for an administrator in IAM?

Tags: amazon-iam

Let's say, I have an user, say *User-A*, that is assigned the following policy (who is essentially an admin user):

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ] 
}
```

Can I create another policy and associate it to *User-A*, so that *User-A* can't launch EC2 instance? (I don't want to disassociate the above policy from *User-A*; because of some legacy reason, I only want to add rules/policies to a user)

Moreover, can I limit launching EC2 instance operation from an AWS account root user? (See the following statement on AWS IAM page)

> When you sign in as the root user, **you have complete, unrestricted
>   access** to all resources in your AWS account, including access to your
>   billing information and the ability to change your password.

Comment: First question, yes, along the lines of `NotAction: "ec2:Launch"`. See the [docs on NotAction](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_notaction.html)

Comment: Second question, sort of: [disown root account permissions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/root-vs-iam.html), but I believe root can still do anything from the web UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can edit the existing policy, then you can change the permissions that are being granted (eg by using `NotAction`, as @bishop suggested).

If you cannot edit the existing policy, you can add another policy with `"Effect": "Deny"` and then list the actions that are *not* permitted.

As to the Root account... It can basically do anything. That is why the recommendation is to attach Multi-Factor Authentication to the account, then lock away the MFA device for emergency use only.